# Cannot cut text from textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, copy-paste

When selecting "cut" from the `TexBox`es' context menu, it works as if I did a "copy".

Same goes if I do a control-x, it simply copies instead of cutting.

Here is my simple dimple xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Window2" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Window2">
    <TextBox/>
</Window>
```

Anybody have any idea what might be wrong?

ENVIRONMENT:

- windows 7 Pro 64 bit
- .net 4.5

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on fresh `WPF` application? Because it's not reproducible with the code you have provided.

Comment: yup. ive just created a sparkling new wpf project with the same one window. same issue. thanks

Comment: No one can help you till you add more details to your question. This is not reproducible at our end.

Comment: id love to add details. but which? its a brand new app. ill add my environment to the question. thanks

Comment: I've got the same issue and I have yet to see the solution for this. In my case, though, I can hit ctrl+x multiple times and only then it magically manages to delete text from my textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my situation, the culprit in the end was vnc viewer

you may find the following interesting or helpful

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798501/textbox-cut-bug-in-wpf

hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue, and found the issue was due to Notepadd++'s Clipboard History feature.  Once I closed the program, cutting worked perfectly.

It is definitely caused by external programs doing clipboard interference (probably incorrectly), as it was Notepad++ for me, and VNC for @Yisman.  It should be considered a WPF bug though, since any non-WPF application can cut perfectly with Notepad++'s Clipboard History running.

My best guess, after looking at the details from the Connect post, is that the copy part of the cut command throws an exception, but throws is after adding the text to the clipboard.  Other programs will still do the delete portion of the cut command, where WPF will skip it.  This is reasonable, as it probably assumes it wasn't added to the clipboard, since the copy failed, but doesn't work well in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some issue using VS2015 on Windows 10 pro 64 bit as a Virtualbox 5.1.6 guest on a OSX host. The "problem" was the Virtualbox Shared clipboard between the guest and a host OS (Guest To Host).